# using cut in a loop script

Tags: bash, mac

I am using bash on my macbook pro. I have a list of files in a directory that I'd like to use the cut command on. When I use this command:

```
cut -d " " -f 6- 2.ostat > 2.ostat1
```

it works nicely - a new file is created and it contains the desired information

When I try to use it in a loop like this:

```
for num in *.ostat; do cut -d " " -f 6- ${num}.ostat > ${num}.1; done
```

it creates new files for all but the files are blank.

Is is possible to use a single (and for a beginner understandable) command to cut out the information I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$num (or ${num}, the braces aren't necessary, references the files. $num.ostat will produce 1.ostat.ostat, 2.ostat.ostat ...

```
for num in *.ostat; do cut -d " " -f 6- $num > $num.1; done
```

should work.

Comment: Can we see a sample file please?

Comment: The content in the file just didn't show immidiately :)

Comment: do I understand correctly, that if I'm in the "desired" directory which contains only files that I want to run my loop on, I do not need to write the files' extension? the scrip will just take everyhting that is there and run it on all?

Comment: Yes; you can use for i in *, and get all files; or specify a filter as in *.ostat, or [2-4]*.ostat & get all files starting in 2,3, or 4 with that extension, or whatever combination you like. Or you could do `for i in {1..5}` & use the index as you were originally trying to do.

Comment: Thanks so much! It's invaluable to get this advice as a beginner :)

Comment: Pleasure! The best way to add thanks is to tick the box to accept the answer, by the way :) - shows the world it's fixed & does the points thing..

Comment: great, I've done that now :)